# MySQL select/where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a webapplication linked to a mysql database with the following fields:

```
field 1:trip_id
field 2:trip_destination
field 3:trip_description
field 4:trip_duration
```

In the webapplication I have a listbox based on the following:

```
ListBox value =1: trip duration 1 - 5 days
ListBox value =2: trip duration 6 - 10 days
Listbox value =3: trip duration 11 -20 days
ListBox value =4: trip duration over 20 days
```

How do I put this in the sql select statement?

Comment: How do you store the trip_duration like a date? Do you want 1 SQL statement or 4?

Comment: I think another example of poor database design why you are not storing as tinyint or enum field trip_duration 1,2,3,4 and rest handle with php

Comment: Do you want to list to the users how each trip is duration-based? (ie listing Trip A is 11-20 days, Trip B is 1-5 days, Trip C is over 20 days???  Or, do you just want the listbox to have a person pick how long a vacation and show which trips are based on the same duration?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM trip_table WHERE trip_duration BETWEEN start_day-1 AND end_day+1;
```

You would then need to replace start_day and end_day with your periods e.g. start_day = 6 end_day=10.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in its simplest form, from your internally controlled values of the listbox ranges (and I'm not a PHP programmer to fill in the blanks), but a query could be.

```
select * 
   from TripTable
   where trip_duration >= ?MinimumDays 
     AND trip_duration <= ?MaximumDays
```

If you are trying to get all trips, and have them pre-stamped with a 1-4 classification, I would apply a CASE WHEN

```
select *,
      case 
         when trip_duration >= 1 and trip_duration <=5 then 1
         when trip_duration >= 6 and trip_duration <=10 then 2
         when trip_duration >= 11 and trip_duration <=20 then 3
         when trip_duration > 20 then 4
      end as TripDurationType
   from
      TripTable
```